# Is there a difference between "gain root privileges" and "execute any command"?

Tags: bash, sudo

I recently opened my sudoers file and noticed the following:

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Is there actually an effective difference between the privileges of `admin` and `sudo` groups? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That section refers to the Runas_Spec part of Sudo, which further details of can be found on [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers).

In your example any members of the admin group may escalate to having sudo priveleges as any user, and members of the sudo group may escalate to having sudo priveleges as any user **and** group.

Example below, I created 2 users and give them the different priveleges outline in your question;

```
cat /etc/sudoers | grep ^test
test1   ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL
test2   ALL=(ALL:ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Then tested having them run commands as the apache user and group, notice the prompt for the password for user test1 when trying to run as the apache group;

```
[test1@heisenbug root]$ sudo -u apache ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.230.233) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from par08s10-in-f9.1e100.net (74.125.230.233): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=36.2 ms
--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 36.245/36.245/36.245/0.000 ms

[test1@heisenbug root]$ sudo -g apache ping google.com
[sudo] password for test1: 

[test2@heisenbug root]$ sudo -u apache ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.230.226) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lhr08s06-in-f2.1e100.net (74.125.230.226): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=34.4 ms
--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 34.465/34.465/34.465/0.000 ms

[test2@heisenbug root]$ sudo -g apache ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.230.233) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lhr08s06-in-f9.1e100.net (74.125.230.233): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=35.0 ms
64 bytes from lhr08s06-in-f9.1e100.net (74.125.230.233): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=33.5 ms
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 33.575/34.308/35.042/0.756 ms
```

I can only imagine a very strict set of circumstances where this type of usage would be applicable.